# Conversion from pseudocode into C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, pseudocode, bloom-filter

Here's my struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int k;          //num of hash functions
    int m;          //num of filter's bit 
    int* hashSeeds; //seed of k hash functions
    bool* filter;   //filter
} BloomFilter;

//Initializated as
BloomFilter bloomFilter;
```

Here's my function

```
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter, const char* elem, int elemLen);
```

(where elem is the element I want to insert in my bloomfilter from an external dataset)
I want to implement the following pseudocode in my void

```
INPUT: delta ∈ E, b, H = {h1, h2, …, hk } OUTPUT: b
1. i ←1;
2. while i ≤ k do
3. b[hi ( delta )] ← 1;
4. i ← i + 1;
```

This is what I did:

```
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,const char* elem,int elemLen)
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=bloomFilter->k) 
    {
        //b[hi(delta)] <- 1 How can I implement this line?
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

I'm confused, I don't understand how to implement the first line inside the while.
Can you help me?

Comment: Need more info about `INPUT: delta ∈ E, b, H = {h1, h2, …, hk } OUTPUT: b`

Comment: INPUT: delta the elem I want to insert, b array of bit and H the set of hash functions.
OUTPUT: array of bit updated

Comment: In that case, where is the list of hash functions? Also, where is the bit array?
`b[hi ( delta )] ← 1` this line invokes the `i-th` hash function, returns position where elem is to be inserted and sets a 1 at that index in the bit array.

Comment: In my struct I have:
    int k;          //num of hash functions
    int m;          //num of filter's bit 
    int* hashSeeds; //seed of k hash functions
But you understood exactly why I'm stucked

Comment: I am assuming, `bool* filter;   //filter` is your bit array. However, `int* hashSeeds; //seed of k hash functions` is a pointer (possibly to an array of integers). We need to access callable functions. IMHO, hash functions are missing!

Comment: I tried both   bloomFilter->hashSeeds(elem);                and
  bloomFilter->filter(elem);
But obviously it says "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type"

Comment: No, don't try anything on the code you have shown above. The hash functions need to be introduced into the picture. Most probably, you will have to setup an array of hash functions, if the source material doesn't tell you how!

Comment: Assuming hashSeeds are indexable by elem in E which in your case is delta? (this also does not seem to make sense, could you please share more details about your problem statement)
 
```cpp
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,const char* elem,int elemLen)
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=bloomFilter->k) 
    {
        b[hi[delta]%k] = true; // How can I implement this line?
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

shouldn't your loop iterate over elements of E? a.k.a `for (i = 0 to E.length)`

Comment: I don't have anything more.
The professor gave me a pseudo code and empty function already prepared

Comment: @SaraBriccoli create some hash functions (simlpe ones), then create an array of function pointers, then add a pointer to this array in your structure; the task is not that daunting, only the syntax is! Search for implementations for Bloom Filter online, such as [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/179135/234836).

Comment: That's is why most people are sure pseudo code is absolutely useless.

Comment: Arrays of bools are inefficient: Each bool is a byte, so that your data structure will use 8 times the amount of memory than really needed. Are you interested in saving memory? (Normally, with a Bloom filter, that's the case - but not sure about your case.) If yes, then you should use bit packing instead.

Answer (score 0):

All this is just a guess and also I code in C++ so I might be syntactically incorrect in C  so read with prejudice... From the info you provided I see it like this:

1. **`b[n]` is `elem[elemLen]`**

   I would expect either 2 arrays (`const char bi[n],char bo[n]`) or one non constant (`char b[n]`)

   Its not clear how your array is encoded. You described `b` as bit array but your `elem` is char (8bit) so is it 1 bit per byte or you have packed 8 bits into 1 char?
2. **`hi(delta)` is i-th hash function applied on delta**

   I expect it returns position up to delta using PRNG and provided i-th hash seed...

Assuming 1 bit per byte and array access from index `0` instead of `1` I would expect something like this (in C++ sorry not confident enough to use malloc):

```cpp
int h(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,int i,int delta) // hi(delta)
   {
   RandSeed=bloomFilter->hashSeeds[i]; // use i-th hash seed
   return i+Random(delta);             // PRNG returning <0,delta) maybe use Random(delta+1)
   }
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,char* b,int n)
   {
   int i;
   char *bi=new char[n];
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) bi[i]=b[i]; // copy input b[] to temp
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) b[i]=0;     // clear output b[]
   for(i=0;i<bloomFilter->k;i++) 
    b[h(bloomFilter,i,delta)%n]=1;
   delete[] bi;
   }
```

There are still problems like `n` is not used ... This would make sense if `n = bloomFilter->k` if not then I would expect 2 nested `for` loops doing "convolution" something like:

```cpp
int h(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,int i,int delta) // hi(delta)
   {
   RandSeed=bloomFilter->hashSeeds[i]; // use i-th hash seed
   return Random(delta);               // PRNG returning <0,delta) maybe use Random(delta+1)
   }
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,char* b,int n)
   {
   int i,j;
   char *bi=new char[n];
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) bi[i]=b[i]; // copy input b[] to temp
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) b[i]=0;     // clear output b[]
   for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
    for(i=0;i<bloomFilter->k;i++) 
     b[(j+h(bloomFilter,i,delta))%n]=1;
   delete[] bi;
   }
```

Also input array is not used so I would expect this is done only for set bits something like this:

```cpp
int h(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,int i,int delta) // hi(delta)
   {
   RandSeed=bloomFilter->hashSeeds[i]; // use i-th hash seed
   return Random(delta);               // PRNG returning <0,delta) maybe use Random(delta+1)
   }
void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,char* b,int n)
   {
   int i,j;
   char *bi=new char[n];
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) bi[i]=b[i]; // copy input b[] to temp
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) b[i]=0;     // clear output b[]
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    if (bi[j])
     for(i=0;i<bloomFilter->k;i++)        
      b[(j+h(bloomFilter,i,delta))%n]=1;
   delete[] bi;
   }
```

Now you can add bit packing (using masks) and maybe centering the "convolution" if needed. However if this is correct I do not know as Bloom Filter is not known to me... This is just how I see it would make sense from given information.